# Optionally add a key in object

Tags: javascript

I want to optionally add a key in object

consider I have a following function

```
const uploadFacebookPostWithPhoto = async (filePath, imageName, longText, linkURL, pageID, accessToken) => {

    const uploadPayload = {
      json: true,
      method: "POST",
      uri: `https://graph.facebook.com/${pageID}/photos`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
      },
      formData: {
        await: "true",
        source: {
          value: filePath.data,
          options: {
            filename: imageName
          }
        },
        message:longText,
        link: linkURL,
      }
    };
    return requestP(uploadPayload); 
}
```

now this function is suppose to be reusable meaning, from the frontend there are two instance from where I would be calling it.

1. In the first instance from where I am calling, I will send some linkURL
2. In the second instance, I will just pass null for linkURL

Now, What I want is If the linkURl is not equal to null my formData should have link key/value pair and if the linkURL is null, my formData shouldn't have linkURL key/Value.

The easiest solution would be to create if-else statement

```
const uploadFacebookPostWithPhoto = async (filePath, imageName, longText, linkURL, pageID, accessToken) => {
if (linkURL) {
        const uploadPayload = {
          json: true,
          method: "POST",
          uri: `https://graph.facebook.com/${pageID}/photos`,
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
          },
          formData: {
            await: "true",
            source: {
              value: filePath.data,
              options: {
                filename: imageName
              }
            },
            message:longText,
            link: linkURL,
          }
        };
        return requestP(uploadPayload); 
} else {
 const uploadPayload = {
          json: true,
          method: "POST",
          uri: `https://graph.facebook.com/${pageID}/photos`,
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
          },
          formData: {
            await: "true",
            source: {
              value: filePath.data,
              options: {
                filename: imageName
              }
            },
            message:longText
          }
        };
        return requestP(uploadPayload); 
}
    }
```

but I was looking for a better solution, Can someone suggest an alternate solution (besides creating a separate function)? Purpose of this question is to improve my code quality

**Note: requestP is just request-promise**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just don't add `link` key in object literal. add it later based on condition

```
const uploadFacebookPostWithPhoto = async (filePath, imageName, longText, linkURL, pageID, accessToken) => {

    const uploadPayload = {
      json: true,
      method: "POST",
      uri: `https://graph.facebook.com/${pageID}/photos`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
      },
      formData: {
        await: "true",
        source: {
          value: filePath.data,
          options: {
            filename: imageName
          }
        },
        message:longText,
      }
    };
    if(linkUrl) uploadPayLoad.formData.link = linkURL,
    return requestP(uploadPayload); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the object spread syntax:

```
formData: {
    await: "true",
    source: {
        value: filePath.data,
        options: {
            filename: imageName
        }
    },
    message:longText,
    ...(linkURL && {link: linkURL})
}
```

`(linkURL && {link: linkURL})` is an expression that can become either `null` (when `linkURL` has that value like you described), or `{link: linkURL}`.

In the first case `...null` has no effect, because `null` does not have properties.

In the second case, a shallow copy of `{link: linkURL}` is merged into the outer object.

Comment: Spread operator is used to create a copies of object? I am still unable to comprehend this line   `...(linkURL && {link: linkURL})` 
Can you please add some explanation for this?

Comment: Of course. I added a few lines of explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a ternary statement with JS `undefined` statement:

```
const uploadFacebookPostWithPhoto = async (filePath, imageName, longText, linkURL, pageID, accessToken) => {

    const uploadPayload = {
      json: true,
      method: "POST",
      uri: `https://graph.facebook.com/${pageID}/photos`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
      },
      formData: {
        await: "true",
        link: linkUrl ? linkUrl : undefined, // If linkUrl, add it. Otherwise, undefined.
        source: {
          value: filePath.data,
          options: {
            filename: imageName
          }
        },
        message:longText,
      }
    };
    return requestP(uploadPayload); 
}
```

Comment: This is already what OP's code is doing mate. OP wants the key `link` itself to not appear in object if `linkURL` is null

Comment: @CodeManiac was just about to comment the same, but ChrisHappy still thanks for answering

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but does the key exist if it's parsed? `JSON.stringify({'link': undefined});` I'm also learning here :D